# Specify a line break in a csv that translates to read.csv() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to add a geom_label that has a line break and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. First I am saving my csv with the line breaks (see below).

[image]

then I am just using `read.csv()` and it gives me data like this:

```
structure(list(State = "Alabama\\n(regulation change)", Year = 2019.666667, 
    position = 35L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

This is my code:

```
library (ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=Year))+
       geom_label(aes(y=position,label=State))
```

This is my plot:

[image]

Why is it not printing a linebreak at `\n`?

Comment: Try with `\n` instead of `\\n`.

Comment: its the same thing when I do that

Comment: R 4.2.2 on Win  with (relatviely) up to date packages and `\n` in `"Alabama\n(regulation change)"` breaks a line just fine in ggplot.

Comment: Ok then it must be something wrong with read.csv() because I specified \n in my csv. Can you look at my revised question and answer it?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out. thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe \n is working , as @stefan suggested please replace \\n with \n

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the csv use `gsub("\\n", "\n", State, fixed = TRUE)` to correct the response listed above